# Why text-transform:capitalize is not working

Tags: css

I intended to capitalize the first letter of the post title, here is the link https://9scoretrain.com/bonus/, but it is not working.

I made this change, style.css

```
h1.entry-title,
h2.entry-title {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize !important; /* Shark */
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is `capitalize` - clear your browser cache or HARD reload. Worpdress can store cache while making changes to CSS.

Comment: It appears to be working.  `document.querySelectorAll("h1.entry-title");` gives a single element ("Bonus") which is capitalized.  `document.querySelectorAll("h2.entry-title");
` gives no elements.  Did you think you had some `h2` elements that should match?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks!! previously I cleaned cache a bunch of times but it is not working. Now is fine. It may take time.

Comment: @user2740650 it is original wordpress code, I just added the text-transform.